# Make backup of an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, store

I have an array of objects of my own classes. That array is the data of a map you can make in my game. My question is how can I set that array in a file so when I go on another pc I can resume with making the map?

Comment: What you're looking for is called serialization. You can use JSON or any other serialization method to save your array to a file.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the object you are storing in the array implements [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface. Then simply use the java serialization ([a sample tutorial](http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-serialization/)).

Answer (score 1):

If your structures are not circular you can use: https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ easily generate JSON from your objects.

Else you can also use google protocol buffers (much cleaner) https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/

Answer (score 0):

Have your own classes implement [Serialization](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serialization.html), add them to a [Collection](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), and use the following code to get them out to a file:

```
FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("game.dat");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(file);
oos.writeObject(myCollectionOfObjects);
oos.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your classes are serializable, you can use ObjectOutputStream to save them and later ObjectInputStream to load.  If you don't know what are serializable objects and how to work with them, start reading [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html).